# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' on line 186

Tags: php, html, condiciones

no se por que aparece este error al parecer tengo un problema con el cierre de mi If pero no lo veo, aqui el codigo:

```html
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['dominioselect'])){ ?>
  <input type="text" id="nomb" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['dominioselect'];?>" name="Nomb" placeholder="Dominio" class="form-control dAceptado"> <br>

<?php}else{?>
  <input type="text" id="nomb"  value="" name="Nomb" placeholder="Dominio" class="form-control"> <br>
<?php } ?>
  <select id="ext" name="Ext" class="custom-select">
                                         
   <option>.com</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: ¿Es ese el contexto de la linea 186? Intenta separar `<?php }else{ ?>`.

Comment: @k3lly.dev al parecer si era eso, no lo veia gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Perdón a la persona que marco la respuesta como mala no se fijo que es lo mismo del comentario que se coloco

Comment: @CesarPiñero No hay de que colega. Cuidado con los errores de sintaxis, son muy dolorosos en ocaciones.

Comment: @YoelRodriguez tu respuesta es más un comentario que una respuesta realmente, no ameritaba escribir una respuesta. Y menos cuando alguien ya brindó una solución.

Comment: Disculpa, lo que sucede es que escribía mi respuesta en el momento en que ud escribía su comentario. Por lo que no pude ver que ud ya lo había hecho. En ningún momento fue mi intención hacerlo así

Comment: @k3lly.dev _siempre_ merece escribir una respuesta. Los comentarios son para pedir aclaraciones. Si das la respuesta en un comentario, nadie puede votar sobre ella, y entonces no funciona el sitio. Ademas, la pregunta se queda sin respuesta. Es mas, es totalmente valido  si alguien toma tu comentario y lo convierte en respuesta, añadiendo mas detalles. No es lo que paso aquí, Yoel ya estaba escribiendo su respuesta, pero mismo si así fuera, no hubiera pasado nada malo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te esta sucediendo es que estas colocando la (}) junto a la etiqueta php en el else Ejemplo: **`<?php}else{?>`** y tiene que quedar así **`<?php }else{ ?>`**

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['dominioselect'])){ 
 $dominio = $_SESSION['dominioselect']; ?>

  <input type="text" id="nomb" value="<?php echo $dominio; ?>" name="Nomb" placeholder="Dominio" class="form-control dAceptado" /> <br>

<?php }else{ ?>
  <input type="text" id="nomb"  value="" name="Nomb" placeholder="Dominio" class="form-control" /> <br>
<?php } ?>
  <select id="ext" name="Ext" class="custom-select">

   <option>.com</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si es posible evita escribir código donde mezcles bloques de HTML/PHP. Es la sintaxis más horrible que conozco, produciendo programas complicados para analizar y depurar.

Propongo para estos casos una técnica muy sencilla que consiste en lo siguiente:

- Trabajar todo dentro de un bloque PHP.
- Para las partes HTML creas una variable (en este caso la he llamado `$html`), y concatenas en esa variable todo lo que necesites. Nótese que esta variable se puede usar en varias partes del código, mediante el operador de concatenación `.=`. Es como ir recogiendo en ella todo el HTML posible.
- Todo el contenido que se vaya a poner dentro de `$html` debe estar rodeado por comillas dobles `"...contenido"`, esto permitirá escribir `$variables` dentro del bloque sin necesidad de unir con el `.` cortando el ritmo.
- Para el contenido que lleva comillas, como las etiquetas `name, class`, etc. debes escapar las mismas con `\`.
- El final solamente se hace `echo $html;` y todo listo.

Esa simpleza produce un código totalmente distinto, elegante, legible, fácil de depurar, sin tantas aperturas y cierres al estilo `<?php ... ?> echo "Hola"  ?>  <select> <?php while () {}`, cuando tienes un código así con cientos o miles de líneas y hay un problema, es imposible analizarlo a simple vista.

Aplicando lo dicho, tu código quedaría así. Otra mejora que he incluido aquí ha sido evaluar el dato de la sesión con un ternario, así sabemos si existe y al mismo tiempo lo guardamos en una variable para luego usar esa variable.

```
<?php
    $dominio=!empty($_SESSION['dominioselect']) ? $_SESSION['dominioselect'] : NULL;
    if ($dominio) {
        $html="<input type=\"text\" id=\"nomb\" value=\"$dominio\" name=\"Nomb\" placeholder=\"Dominio\" class=\"form-control dAceptado\"> <br>";
    }else{
      $html="<input type=\"text\" id=\"nomb\" name=\"Nomb\" placeholder=\"Dominio\" class=\"form-control\"> <br>";
    } 
    $html.="<select id=\"ext\" name=\"Ext\" class=\"custom-select\">
                   <option value=\"com\">.com</option>
              </select>";
    echo $html;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### *Se que la respuesta ya fue resuelta, pero quería añadir algo mas.*

Como ya lo mencionaron en [la respuesta por Yoel Rodriguez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/258863/39913) el error estaba en escribir el `}` junto a la etiqueta `<?php`, que envés de `<?php}else{?>` Debías escribir `<?php }else{ ?>`.

Para evitar mayormente esta clase de errores, te recomiendo usar ["Alternative syntax for control structure"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). Esta sintaxis alternativa es muy útil cuando mezclas php con html, pues eliminas el uso de corchetes cerrándose y abriéndose por todas partes.

#### Ejemplo con tu código

```php
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['dominioselect'])): ?>
  <?php $dominio = $_SESSION['dominioselect']; ?>
  <input type="text" id="nomb" value="<?php echo $dominio; ?>" name="Nomb" placeholder="Dominio" class="form-control dAceptado" /> <br>
<?php else: ?>
  <input type="text" id="nomb"  value="" name="Nomb" placeholder="Dominio" class="form-control" /> <br>
<?php endif; ?>
<select id="ext" name="Ext" class="custom-select">
   <option>.com</option>
</select>
```

Como ves es mas fácil de leer que usando `{}` y te ahorras errores como este.